Plotting CSV datapoints as candlesticks
I'm trying to turn my tick csv data into 1min candle stick charts on matplotlib, I have two columns in the csv. ts_event (time) and price. here is what they look like. (2024-04-18 00:00:00+00:00,  5066.50). Im not very experienced into using matplotlib and asked gpt. this is what they gave me.
prices = df['price']
time = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_event'])

# Combine data into a DataFrame
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'price': prices})

# Resample data to 1-minute intervals and aggregate OHLC
ohlc = sample_df.set_index('time').resample('min').agg({'price': ['first', 'max', 'min', 'last']})
print(ohlc)

# Plotting candlestick chart using mplfinance
fplt.plot(ohlc,type='candle')

# Show the plot
fplt.show()

this is what the output of OHLC looks like:
                             first      max      min     last
time                                                         
2024-04-18 00:00:00+00:00  5066.50  5066.75  5064.75  5065.00

This is the error I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\=======\Desktop\script.py", line 20, in <module>
    fplt.plot(ohlc,type='candle')
  File "C:\Users\=======\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mplfinance\plotting.py", line 417, in plot
    dates,opens,highs,lows,closes,volumes = _check_and_prepare_data(data, config)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\======\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mplfinance\_arg_validators.py", line 54, in _check_and_prepare_data
    if dc.strip() != dc:
       ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

I am not sure where to go from here, as I do not understand those errors, and when I gave the error to Chatgpt it just reproduced the above code and the same error still existed.

It would be helpful what is the fplt in your code and how did you import it.

Once again chatGPT proves that it does not know how to write code!   There is no substitute for actually learning how to code.

Regarding "I have two columns in the csv. ts_event (time) and price. here is what they look like. (2024-04-18 00:00:00+00:00, 5066.50)." Please provide at least 30 such data points so that we can demonstrate how to prepare your data for a candlestick chart, and how to make the chart.

Alternatively see Single time-series value to OHLC data and this example.

You can do this:
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as fplt


data = {'ts_event': ['2024-04-18 00:00:00+00:00', '2024-04-18 00:00:30+00:00', '2024-04-18 00:01:00+00:00', '2024-04-18 00:01:30+00:00'],
        'price': [5066.50, 5066.75, 5064.75, 5065.00]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['ts_event'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_event'])

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'time': df['ts_event'], 'price': df['price']})

ohlc = sample_df.set_index('time').resample('1T').agg({'price': ['first', 'max', 'min', 'last']})
ohlc.columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
ohlc.reset_index(inplace=True)

fplt.plot(ohlc.set_index('time'), type='candle')
fplt.show()

which gives

